# I got error on Xcode7 for String

Tags: ios, swift

The error is "Cannot convert value of type'[AnyObject]' to expected argument type '[String]?'". Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
   func send() {
    let picker = MFMailComposeViewController()
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self
    picker.setSubject(subject.text!)
     //the code below is the reason I got error for
    picker.setToRecipients(Const.CONTACT_MAIL)
    picker.setMessageBody(body.text, isHTML: true)
    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: What is Const in your code?

Comment: this line need the expected type Const.CONTACT_MAIL

Comment: You should pass the String only

Comment: like (Const.String)? How should code look like?

Answer (score 1):

setToRecipients is expecting an array of strings.  The Apple documentation gives this example

```
picker.setToRecipients(["address@example.com"])
```

Comment: If you like the answer you need to tick it to encourage people to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

If Const.CONTACT_MAIL is a string then you can simply try this:

```
picker.setToRecipients([Const.CONTACT_MAIL])
```

It is because it expects an array